# Pyspark user defined aggregate calculation on columns

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sklearn-pandas

I’m preparing data for input for a classifier in Pyspark. I have been using aggregate functions in SparkSQL to extract features such as average and variance. These are grouped by activity, name and window. Window has been calculated by dividing a unix timestamp by 10000 to break into 10 second time windows.

```py
sample = sqlContext.sql("SELECT activity, name, window, avg(acc_x) as avgX , variance(acc_x) as varX FROM data  GROUP BY activity,name,window ORDER BY activity,name,window")
```

The result of this would look like

```
Activity  Name         Window       AvgX       VarX
Walk    accelerometer  95875        2.0          1.0
```

What I want to do now, is to calculate the average slope of each point in X.

To this I need timestamp, window, and X. I have implemented the logic in Python, using arrays, this is what it would look like – calculating the slope between each point, and then getting the average slope. Ideally, I would like to do this in a UDAF , which is not yet supported in Pyspark. (It would look like this , say if function below was called slope. Then in sql you could do `slope(timestamp, X) as avgSlopeX`

**EDIT - changed input so it is clearer.**
So, what I am doing exactly is computing the slope between each point, and then returning the average of the slopes in that window. So, as I am getting the average and variance of each window, I also want to get the average slope.

```py
#sample input
timestamp = [1464703425544,1464703426534,1464703427551,1464703428587,1464703429512,1464703430493,1464703431505,1464703432543,1464703433513,1464703434529]

values = [1021.31,1021.26,1021.19,1021.19,1021.1,1021.1,1021.1, 1021.05,1021.02]

i = 0; 
slope = 0.0;
totalSlope = 0.0;

while (i < len(timestamp) - 1):
    y2 = values[i+1];
    y1 = values[i];

    x2 = timestamp[i + 1];
    x1 = timestamp[i]; 
    slope = ((y2-y1)/(x2-x1)); 
    totalSlope = totalSlope + slope;
    i=i+1

avgSlope = (totalSlope/len(x_values))
```

How can I implement this? Should I try converting to a pandas dataframe then a numpy array? If so, how can I make sure data will still be mapped properly, keeping in mind the GROUP BY activity, name window in the sql query.

Comment: This is definitely not a job for UDAF.

Comment: @zero323 how would you approach this?

Comment: Compute slope for consecutive points and then take simple average. But input description here is rather vague. Could you post example data with expected output?

Comment: In particular do you expect slope between `windows`? If not where are the timestamp to determine order of rows?

Comment: @zero323 I've edited the sample input to make it clearer. Computing the slope of consecutive points and getting the average is exactly what I want to do, but don't know what the right approach would be doing it in Spark.

Comment: I was thinking more about SQL / DF schema :)

Comment: @zero323 I'm going to try and do it by converting to pandas then numpy, but that will be very inefficient. :( If you were to do it, how would you go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general this is not a job for UDAF because UDAFs don't provide any means to define the order. It looks like what you really need here is some combination of window functions and standard aggregations.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lag, avg
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = ... 
## DataFrame[activity: string, name: string, window: bigint, 
##   timestamp: bigint, value: float]

group = ["activity", "name", "window"]

w = (Window()
    .partitionBy(*group)
    .orderBy("timestamp"))

v_diff = col("value") - lag("value", 1).over(w)
t_diff = col("timestamp") - lag("timestamp", 1).over(w)

slope = v_diff / t_diff

df.withColumn("slope", slope).groupBy(*group).agg(avg(col("slope")))
```

Comment: this seems like a good approach! but, withColumn seems to ignore "slope" and just returns the average of value instead :/ if slope was registered as a regular function could it be used?

Comment: Typo. It should be slope in agg clause.